Summation notation with 1 as the function
Can you please explain how this sum is read:
$\displaystyle N(T) := \sum_{0<\gamma\leq T} 1$
Summation index is $\gamma$ but the function is just $1$. What are we summing?
I've taken it from here (p.2)

It just means you are adding a 1 for each $\gamma$ that is summed over, in other words, it is the size of the set ${\gamma : 0 < \gamma \leq T}$

Ok, makes sense. I understand that $\gamma$ is the size of the set. But I don't understand, how this is a "function." We count the imaginary parts up to $T$. There is no function that counts this. Do we have $\displaystyle \sum_{0<\gamma\leq T} 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\ldots$. Sorry if I'm complicating something simple.

Yes, you are literally adding the integer 1 repeatedly, with one 1 for each element in the set, so you get the total size of the set overall.

You're (presumably) used to this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^4 \color{red}{\boxed{i^3}} = \overbrace{1^3}^{\color{red}{i^3}|_{i=1}}
+ \overbrace{2^3}^{\color{red}{i^3}|_{i=2}}
+ \overbrace{3^3}^{\color{red}{i^3}|_{i=3}}
+ \overbrace{4^3}^{\color{red}{i^3}|_{i=4}}$$
So for each term of the sum, we evaluate the expression being summed with a given value of $i$.
Similarly,
$$\sum_{i=1}^4 \color{red}{\boxed{1}} = \overbrace{1}^{\color{red}{1}|_{i=1}}
+ \overbrace{1}^{\color{red}{1}|_{i=2}}
+ \overbrace{1}^{\color{red}{1}|_{i=3}}
+ \overbrace{1}^{\color{red}{1}|_{i=4}}$$
If we evaluate the expression "1" with a specific value of $i$... well, $i$'s value doesn't matter, the answer is 1!
If you want to say the red expression is a function, it would be the constant function $\mathbf{1}$, that takes in any number and returns 1. So $\mathbf{1}(0) = 1$, and $\mathbf{1}(28) = 1$, and $\mathbf{1}(-\pi\sqrt{83}) = 1$... (It's not a very exciting function.)

That's great thanks. But still, since $0<\gamma \leq T$ and $T$ is given, then $\gamma$ will be $\gamma = T$. We add up 1s to obtain the given $T$. We might as well say $\gamma = T$. But that's nitpicking, I understand the notation now, thanks again.

@zeynel $T$ is the upper bound for $\gamma$, not the count of $\gamma$s. You're not summing over integers in this case - $\gamma$ can be any real number between $0$ and $T$ (that appears as the imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta$).
